# How to use AWS Cognito SSO with Backend Server Hosted on Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, backend, amazon-cognito

My organization has Single Sign On set up with AWS Cognito. While my department wants to use Azure to host the backend service.

How do I integrate the two? I'll need authorisation before users are allowed to request to the backend server on Azure

Answer (score 0):

You can use Amazon Cognito SDK/API to integrate with your backend app.